# Elastic Search No server available, list index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, elasticsearch, pyes

I'm trying to get a simple example working with elastic search using pyes, but I'm having trouble getting the starting examples working. I'm following the documentation found here: http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/usage.html

and just trying to run the following function, but It's not quite working.

```
def index_transcripts():
    conn = ES('127.0.0.1:9200')
    conn.indices.create_index("test-index")

index_transcripts()
```

Which in my mind should be very straightforward, but instead I get the following error:

```
pyes.exceptions.NoServerAvailable: list index out of range
```

I'm just starting out with Elastic Search and pyes seems like a wonderful library, but I'm clearly uncertain on how exactly I should use it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
ES(server=[('http', 'localhost', 9200)])
```

Server is a list of tuples.

Documentation to this is here:
http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/references/pyes.connection.html

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't update this question. Turns out the only problem here is that the ES create method as bound by pyes doesn't wait for the es instance to actually be created before moving on. When I passed the ES object in from outside the method this worked fine. Ended up not using pyes for this project because of silly issues like this, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Actually, it does not really matter defining server like above. It is the most descriptive way, but not required.

I also get this error and did not find a good solution. Deleting indices from elasticsearch throws the error but after a couple of indexing it occurs again. I tried both defining server es ES() and ES[] but none works.