# Elasticsearch is missing data when querying after insert

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I have a test that does the following:

1. create an index on ES using pyes
2. insert mapping
3. insert data
4. query the data to check if it fits the expected result

However when I run this test, sometimes it would find no result, and sometimes it would find something but some data is missing. The interesting thing is this only happens when I run the test automatically. If I type in the code ling-by-line, everything works as expected. I've tested it 3 times manually and it works without failure.

Sometimes I've even received this message:

```
NoServerAvailable: list index out of range
```

It seems like the index was not created at all

I've pinged my ES address and everything looks correct. There was no other error msg found anywhere.

I thought it would be because I was trying to get the data too fast after the insert, as documented here: [Elastic Search No server available, list index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905295/elastic-search-no-server-available-list-index-out-of-range)

(check first comment in the accepted answer)

However, even if I make it delay for 4 seconds or so, this problem still happens. What concerns me is the fact that sometimes only SOME data is missing, which is really strange. I thought it would be either finding it all or missing it all.

Anyone got similar experience that can shine some light on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Share your code for the 4 steps you mentioned.

Comment: there's refresh API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is Near Realtime(NRT). It might take upto 1 second to make your recently indexed document be visible/available for search. 
To make your recently indexed document available instantly for searching, you can append `?refresh=wait_for` at the end of the index document command. For e.g.,

```
POST index/type?refresh=wait_for
{
  "field1":"test",
  "field2":2,
  "field3":"testing"
}
```

`?refresh=wait_for` will forcibly refresh your index to make the recently indexed document available for search. Refer [?refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html).